# Word 2010/2013 - add a tick symbol to shapes

Tags: microsoft-word, shapes

Word's insert shapes feature is great but I can't find a tick symbol anywhere.

Now of course I can add a symbol (i.e. font character) but I want a picture I can easily re-position on the page and layer.

I could just insert a tick image from the web but I don't want to have to mess around removing backgrounds and I'd like it to be permanently available in the shapes pane.

Comment: I don't think you can. Personally, I would get the tick from the web, remove the back ground and keep it saved some where so you can always refer to it.

Comment: Thanks Dave - will do.  Gee bit of an oversight for the product team not to have this in shapes.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you google the word 'tick' and save as a picture and then insert the picture into your Word document.  This will allow you to move it around and resize it as needed.